# Как разнести один persistence-unit по нескольким файлам?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Сейчас у меня есть файл persistence.xml в папке resources\META-INF, в котором я указал класс провайдера, настройки подключения к БД, а также файлы с нативными запросами. Я смотрю исходники BroadleafCommerce, чтобы изучить на ее примере хибер и спринг, и заметил, что у них нет файла persistence.xml. Вместо этого у них в каждом подпроекте есть отдельные файлы вроде persistence-common.xml, persistence-cms.xml и т.д.

В каждом из них есть persistence-unit name="blPU", т.е. получается что один PU разнесен по нескольким файлам. Я подумал, что благодаря приставке persistence хибер сам сможет найти все такие файлы, попробовал повторить, но не получилось. Возможно, это спринговая фича, или используется какая-то сторонняя библиотека.

Не могли бы мне подсказать как такое можно сделать?